# How can I list all my unread messages in LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

I wonder how I can list all my unread messages in LinkedIn. I am aware of the "Unread" category in the mailbox, but in my case it is empty while the new message icon indicate the presence of 18 unread messages:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's a bug**. LinkedIn has to fix it but they are not caring about it.

[Here is a thread on Help Center](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/list/search/1/d/c/sort/newest/topic/messages+unread) where people have complained about it but there is no response from LinkedIn.